# Parsing a complicated two files

Tags: php, arrays, file, parsing, explode

File 1 Values:

```
....
Group   2012_fln
{
    vnum    103
    Type    mixed
    1   1167    1   2
    2   7731    1   2
    3   3561    1   2
    4   8613    1   3
}

Group   7612_edb
{
    vnum    104
    Type    other
    1   6312    1   90
    2   5241    5   45
....
```

File 2 Values:

```
....
1167    ºÎÈ°Àı´Ş°¿
7731    ÀÌÆÄÀÇ
3561    »¡°£»ö
....
```

All values has been seperated with TABs. By the way there is thousands of values in both files.

So here is my question:

I need to check values on File 1. Exists or not in File 2.
If 1167 or 7731 or 3561 or 8613 values is not exists in values of File 2.

I need to do that in every group. And if not exist I need a error echo, like; in group xxx, xxx vnum is not exists. And continue to end of File 1.

I tried to explode but there is so much syntaxes in File 1, like Group, { }, vnum, type etc. I know, it's very complicated thats why I wrote here.

I can parse my File 2 values like that:

```
$line = trim($line);

$token = explode("\t", $line);

if ("" == $token[0] or "VNUM" == $token[0])
    continue;

$vnum = $token[0];
$entry_name = $token[1];
```

So, I really need a big help, I spent my last two days in this issue... I hope, I explained properly.

Comment: Do you only care about matching the lines with 4 tab-separated numbers?

Comment: I just need to get numbers in second tab; like : 1   1167    1   2, "1167".

Comment: You can do two explodes in succession. For instance: The first explode on `'}'` and the second on linebreaks `PHP_EOL`. Now you've got an array for each group. Get the number you want from all lines except the first five with `substr()` and you're done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is the second column and the format is the same for all of those rows where you need a value, load the file into a string using `file_get_contents($file1)` and match that pattern (4 numbers separated by whitespace).

Something like:

```
preg_match_all('/^\s*\d+\s+(\d+)\s+\d+\s+\d+\s*$/m', $data, $matches);
```

which would set `$matches` to an array like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>     1   1167    1   2
            [1] =>     2   7731    1   2
            [2] =>     3   3561    1   2
            [3] =>     4   8613    1   3
            [4] =>     1   6312    1   90
            [5] =>     2   5241    5   45
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1167
            [1] => 7731
            [2] => 3561
            [3] => 8613
            [4] => 6312
            [5] => 5241
        )

)
```

`$matches[1]` will be an array of all the values from the second column. You can foreach loop over `$matches[1]` comparing to see if that value is in the second file. I would suggest loading the second file first and generating an index so as you loop over the matches you can just check if `array_key_exists($value, $file2Index)`.

Example, per request:

```
<?php
//read the first file in as a string
$file1 = file_get_contents("/path/to/file1");
//read the second file in as an array
$file2 = file("/path/to/file2");

//index from file2 that we are going to build
$file2Index = array();

foreach($file2 as $line){
    //split the line
    $line = explode("\t", $line, 2);
    //validate the line, should be only 2 values after explode and first should be a number
    if(count($line) == 2 && is_numeric($line[0])){
        //add to index
        $file2Index[$line[0]] = $line[1];
    }
}

//now get all the values from file1 that we want (second column)
preg_match_all('/^\s*\d+\s*(\d+)\s*\d+\s*\d+\s*$/m', $data, $matches);

$file1Values = array_unique($matches[1]);

//loop over the matches from column 2
foreach($file1Values as $value){
    //check if the key doesn't exist
    if(!isset($file2Index[$value])){
        //echo error message
        echo "Value {$value} does not exist in file2<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `isset` over `array_key_exists`. That's a (pseudo) constant operation vs a linear operation

Comment: @wilkesybear that works too as long as you don't want to return a false negative if the value is null. In this case that is likely not an issue as you would be building the index yourself.

Comment: Right, good point. But since "we're" making the array we can make each value be `'key' => true` to assure that `isset` behaves correctly.

Comment: `$file1 = file_get_contents("dataparser\file1.txt");
preg_match_all('/^\s*\d+\s*(\d+)\s*\d+\s*\d+\s*$/m', $file1, $matches);
print_r ($matches[1]);`

returns:

`Array ( [0] => 50721 [1] => 50723 [2] => 50721 [3] => 50723 [4].....`

Alright, I did your technique, I successfully get the Vnums but there are lots of duplicate Vnums, so how can I prevent duplicated numbers?

Comment: Thank you so much, $data variable not given in your codes sir, isn't that should be $file1 ?

Comment: Yes, I don't have sample data to run so I just wrote it without running. `$data` should be `$file1`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using regular expressions to parse your data, as it looks like each line follows a certain format. For file one, you could set up an expression like

```
^\t(\d+)\t(\d+)\t(\d+)\t(\d+)
```

This says to match a tab, followed by at least one digit character, four times. Any line that matches that will be the one you care about. From there, you are interested in the second grouping, or `$2`

For file two, you'll probably want something like

```
^(\d+).*
```

This says, match at least one digit that starts the line, and then anything else. So, you care about the first (and only) grouping, `$1`.

Construct a map of numbers from either the first file or second file, and then iterate over the matches from the other file and check against that map.

Since you are using php, you can use `preg_match` for the regex http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php